# ANOVA P-value adjustments for semi-continuous data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, p-value, post-hoc, nested-data

In tests such as the Bonferroni post-hoc p-value adjustment test, convention is to correct the data with a constant, equivalent to the length (number) of pairwise comparisons that are being performed.  This makes sense with a reasonable and finite number of discrete groups, but not with semi-continuous data as comparisons can rise very quickly.  (Note shouldn't be modeled continuously with a regression).

The experimental model is `Response ~ Condition+Date+ Error(Date)` {as implemented in R using the `aov` function}

The selected mixed model ANOVA currently does a great job but because of the statistical power obtained by the random repeated measure I would like to adjust the p-value to make it more conservative with a p-value adjustment.

In this case of semi-continuous data however, I have no idea what a reasonable number of comparisons to simulate the length variable will be

1. Would there be any merit to use the number of replicates (usually 3-4) as the value for the the correction.  Because the date (repeated experiments) is what contributes to statistical convergence it to me may be the most real-world and constant variable to relate to...
2. If not, what would be an acceptable factor to use in a p-value adjustment test that honors the spirit of this length variable without getting carried away with numerous pair-wise comparisons..
3. I would also be open to an alternate post-hoc test well suited to a multivariate approach.  I am hesitant to use the word nested, but there may be a concept I can extrapolate and transfer from.