# Post-tests to consider in mixed models

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, mixed-model, post-hoc

I have a mixed model of the form `y~condition + Replicate + Error(Replicate)` but at the moment, and am running into difficulties in performing a post-hoc test.

I know there is no best option and it entirely depends on experimental design and the characteristics of my data, so I am hoping to find out a few options that I should investigate and attempt to implement.

In the past I have used `Tukey Kramer` and `Dunnet` using `R` and `glht` i.e. `glht(model, linfct=mcp(Group="Dunnett"))` but at this time I have to stay with `aov()` which unfortunately the `glht` function can't accept as in input model, and `aov()` can't apply more than a single layer of variables to it's multiple comparisons i.e. can't use this multiple comparison to account for my random effect.

1. If anyone knows of a multiple comparisons package that can do a post-hoc test compatible with the `aov()` model I would love to give it a try.
2. If anyone can recommend some post-tests that can be used to make my p-value a little less conservative I would also be interested to investigate it.  The usual p-value adjustment tests don't seem to be quite suitable because of the semi-continuous nature of the point sampling (These aren't quite discrete groups which makes the length variable impossible to determine.  [ANOVA P-value adjustments for semi-continuous data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130751/anova-p-value-adjustments-for-semi-continuous-data))

Comment: I don't really understand point 2, even after looking at the link you provide. What 'length' variable? Is it 'condition' that is semi-continuous? Say more about this point sampling and how it relates to the factors in the experiment.

Comment: @rvl the length variable is a notation I adopted from "n 
number of comparisons, must be at least length(p); only set this (to non-default) when you know what you are doing!" - https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html

Comment: Well this seems problematic, then, because you're worried about the adjustment being too conservative, and `n` must be at least equal to the number of P values being considered. You can only increase `n`, so you can only make it MORE conservative. But in a way that's beside the point. I still don't understand why you think it's too conservative, or what error rate you are trying to control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **lsmeans** package does support `aovlist` objects, but you should do something like `options(contrasts="contr.sum","contr.poly")` *before* fitting the model, to ensure the dummy variables for factors sum to zero. This is necessary because the intercept is put in a separate stratum and we want the rest of the effects to be orthogonal to it. You can then do something like

```
library(lsmeans)
( mod.lsm = lsmeans(model, "condition") )
contrast(mod.lsm, "trt.vs.ctrl")
```

If your data are unbalanced, though, I'd suggest you install the `lme4` package, and fit your model using `lmer` with a model like `y ~ condition + (1 | Replicate)`, which is the analogous model. The above statements still work exactly as shown, without the need to change the `contrasts` options. In the `contrast` call, there are several other options such as `"pairwise"` in case you don't want Dunnett style contrasts.

Comment: Would you per chance know what the lmer equivalent of `y~condition + Replicate + Error(Replicate)` is it close to `Y ~ Condition + (1 | Condition:Replicate)`  I believe the `:` implies nested but I do not want a nested variable and I am not sure how to keep it additive.

Comment: Yes: the last term would just be `(1|Replicate)`.

Comment: Is it to be expected that the results of `Aov` and `lmer` don't quite match up?  Thanks!

Comment: If there is a term in more than one stratum, yes.

Comment: I don't follow quite how stratified sampling will have an effect.  The way I understand my data's factors there is no way for a data point to belong to more than one group...  What would be the best way to use the outputs to back track for this.  I notice that the summary models for `aov` and `lmer` have different DOF.

Comment: It isn't stratified sampling I was talking about. It is the error strata resulting from the `Error()` term in the `aov' model